# How to append array to div in table format

Tags: php, jquery

Html :

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo get_base_url(); ?>admin/test_pad/test_get_car_availability_record",
    type : 'POST',
    data: file_data,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    success:function(response)
    {
      $('#result').append(response);
    }   
});
```

In response of ajax i am getting array in format :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [car_availability_id] => 1 [0] => 1 [car_id] => 1 [1] => 1 [car_category_id] => 1 [2] => 1 [from_date_time] => 2016-09-06 00:00:00 [3] => 2016-09-06 00:00:00 [to_date_time] => 2016-09-07 00:00:00 [4] => 2016-09-07 00:00:00 [is_booked] => no [5] => no [booking_id] => 455 [6] => 455 [from_destination_exists] => no [7] => no [from_destination_id] => 5 [8] => 5 [to_destination_exists] => no [9] => no [to_destination_id] => 546 [10] => 546 [spot_fare] => 0.0000 [11] => 0.0000 [fare] => 6 [12] => 6 [dt_modified] => 2016-09-06 12:54:02 [13] => 2016-09-06 12:54:02 [dt_created] => 2016-09-06 12:54:02 [14] => 2016-09-06 12:54:02 ) )
```

But response should get printed in the table format.
I have tried many things but not getting proper output.

Comment: could you add your php code??

Comment: PHP code is working fine.And I am getting response in success function only thing is I am unable to append it in table format.

Comment: can you add what you get in success console.log the response

Comment: The array added in question is what I am getting in success.

Comment: did u echo the table or the array?? i think you echo the array instead of the table..

Comment: Hey dass thank you so much...you solved my problem..Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcom :)